# Windows looping back to login screen for admin account

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, administrator, login-screen, windows-insider

I have two accounts on my PC. A personal one for my own use, which has got all the administrative rights and requires a PIN to login. And the other I made for my friend with no privileges and no password/PIN. Everything was going fine until I decided to enroll for windows insider's program. Since, I've updated to the insider build, I can no longer login to my own account. When I click on my own account it prompts me to enter my PIN and when I'm done with it login screen disappears but Desktop is not shown. Instead a black screen is shown for a while (approx 1-2 secs) then it reverts back to login screen.

I've no problem with the other account and I can simply login to that account like nothing happened. Also, when I try to do something that requires administrative rights with this account, it prompt me to enter the PIN and when I enter the correct PIN, that task is performed normally like nothing has happened to the admin account.

What I've already tried:

- Restarting my PC several times
- Entering password instead of PIN on login screen
- Resetting my Microsoft account password and login using that
- Sleep and shut down options from the guest account
- Ctrl+Alt+Del from that short-lived black screen
- Reverting back to the previous version of Windows 10

But nothing seems to be helpful. So my question is: **Is there any way to recover that admin account without reinstalling windows/resetting PC?**

Comment: I would try to remove the pin or login using the windows password and see if that works. I believe that when you are on the login screen to enter your pin, and you enter it wrong 5 times, it allows you to use the windows password.

Comment: True But you can switch to password directly too and I've tried that too...Just forgot to mention

Comment: Tried resetting your password and login using that?

Comment: Just tried.......no use... perhaps its not the credentials issue as PIN also worked to login but there's something that prevents desktop from loading and loading login screen instead

Comment: Yeah, very possible. Next best thing is to create a new user and copy all files over to the new profile.

Comment: Sounds good but can I somehow create another account using a non-admin account? I can't find out a way to do so...

Comment: Yes, start a command prompt as admin and enter your pin. Then use `net user newusername * /add` to create the user, then `net localgroup Administrators newusername /add` to add that user to the administrators group.

Comment: Nice to have all that data back but I have to sign in to all my accounts again for this particular user account...No saved passwords...No saved preferences (themes etc)... I won't delete the previous account as I still want to recover thaat

Comment: “can I somehow create another account using a non-admin account? ” - Of course, enable the built in Administrator account, and create the account